# Get new Instace of Controller or Managed Bean

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

The problem that present here is a solution that I am thinking about a particular situation.

Technology Stack: Primefaces, JSF and Spring Framework.

My application

My Web App shows the result of a report in a DataTable of Primefaces. The report has to open in a new tab of the browser. The datable table uses the filters in the datatable header. I have only one view XHTML where the reports it is showed.

My design

```
@ViewScope
@Controller
public class MBReport implements Serializable {

private transient LazyDataModel<String[]> lazyData;

public void report1(){
    lazyData = new...
}
public void report2(){
    lazyData = new...
}
public void report3(){
    lazyData = new...
}

//setters and getters

}
```

My problem

When I show the first report no have problem. When I show the second report no have problem. But, when I try to use the filters of the first report the app crash, because it has lost the reference pointer, and it has been replaced by the second report.
I have the idea if I make a different instance object of the Controller with each request, the problem will be solved, but I cannot to do. I tried with the faces scope (viewscope, flowscope, resquestscope) and Spring beans scope (request, session and application).

The fast solution is to make various View files and lazyData field. But that I don’t like so much.

Could you help me with some ideas for my problem?

Comment: You can't mix annotations for different kinds of beans. I don't use Spring, but CDI beans would be Named and ViewScoped and should work for your case (each tab gets its own ViewScoped bean). If you have to use Spring you should search for how to make a Spring bean viewscoped, I see people used to code this scope themselves

Comment: @Jaqen H'gha Thank you. I'll try to implement the spring view scope, because the viewscope of faces didn't work.